# PHP IF statement and looping

Tags: php, if-statement

I have this php code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['gen'])){              

$genapi = "http://domain.com/api.php";
$result5 = htmlentities(file_get_contents($genapi));

list($first, $last) = explode(':', $result5);

header('Location: minecraft.php?line='.$result5);

}
?>
```

I am having trouble making it so if "$result5" returns with "no" then to wait 2 seconds then try again but if "$result5" does NOT return with "no" it will run the header line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST['gen'])){ 

$loop = true;

  while($loop){
    $genapi = "http://domain.com/api.php";
    $result5 = htmlentities(file_get_contents($genapi));

    if($result5 !== 'no'){ // check your $result5 based on the value it returns
       $loop = false;
       list($first, $last) = explode(':', $result5);
       header('Location: minecraft.php?line='.$result5);
    }
    else{
      sleep(2);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Where does it check if result5 returned "no"?